# SharePoint 2010 Licensing Costs

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

We will be implementing a public-facing website in SharePoint 2010 and I have a few questions regarding licensing:

1. Is there any (relatively) reliable pricing information available for SharePoint 2010? What about rumors?
2. What edition of SharePoint 2010 would be appropriate for a publicly facing website (in 2007, you needed Enterprise for this, but it seems that WCM functionality is included in Standard in 2010)?
3. What would be a reasonable number to budget for SharePoint 2010 licensing for a publicly facing website?

Note: I have tried asking Microsoft directly. Unless you are a volume license customer, they direct you to a reseller (like CDW). Unfortunately, none of the resellers have the pricing for 2010 yet. The sku isn't even in their system.

I was able to get in touch with the Microsoft Pre-Sales team and they confirmed that the price list will for 2010 will be published on May 3rd (or thereabouts), but they weren't able to give me a price.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Government contracts are a great way to sanity check this type of information, if you understand how the product is sold.

According to the [New York State Microsoft Select contract](http://www.ogs.state.ny.us/purchase/snt/awardnotes/7630418766can.HTM) (see the "price list" link):

- SharePoint for Internet Sites *Standard* is $9,257 list and $7,389 for the state
- SharePoint for Internet Sites *Enterprise* is $32,490 list, and $25,936 for the state

Note that state governments get MS Select Level D pricing as a ceiling price.

You can find these items on page 10 of the price list.

Answer (score 1):

you could always buy sharepoint 2007 w/ SA and not worry about 2010 pricing

Comment: Yes, this would be one option. The problem is that I've "heard" that the internet option in 2010 will be about half the cost of the 2007 equivalent. Until we know something conclusive though, using the 2007 pricing is probably best for budgeting purposes...

Answer (score 0):

http://www.microsoftvolumelicensing.com/ProductPage.aspx?pid=320

check that out...if you understand your points, it may make sense.